# Does java have something similar to C# properties?

Tags: c#, java, properties

C# properties (I mean get and set methods) are a very useful feature. Does java have something similar to C# properties too? I mean how we can implement something like the following C# code in java:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }

    set
    {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: See [getters/setters in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875033/getters-setters-in-java)

Comment: Also see CodePorting C#2Java Cloud-App http://codeporting.com/blog/csharp-to-java-conversion/archive/2012/05/09/migrating-c-properties-to-java-using-codeporting-c2java.html that translates C# properties to java automatically while C# code is ported to java.

Comment: Actually, you may omit the get and set prefixes and and use like for example public String name() {...} for the getter and public void name(String val) {...} for the setter. "set" and  "get" are conventional but its very obvious that you are setting when you write name("Lem") and getting String n = name();

Comment: @Scott That is not what OP asked. That functionality (something very similar) is already provided by Lombok soon after Java 5 came out.

Comment: Traditional Java does not support, but Groovy supports it. Since they are compatible and approximately all Java is valid Groovy, that is a way to go if you need properties in Java.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

No, Java does not have the equivalence.  It only has accessor and mutator methods, fancy names for getter and setter methods.  For example:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Comment: It should be clear that these getter/setter methods are not separate constructs with flashy syntax like properties are in C#. Instead, they are just ordinary methods that we happen to name getName() and setName() and task them with acting as properties by convention rather than through dedicated language constructs.

Comment: True, getName() are setName() are so-named purely by convention.  One could just decide to name these methods as, for example, retrieveUserName() and assignUserName(), and that would be just OK.  This kind of convention is idiomatic in Java and tools like Eclipse IDE follow.

Comment: It's not **just** a convention.  There is a specification to go along with Java Beans and an API that makes them useful. http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/docs/spec.html

Comment: @ChrisNava your link has rotted.

Comment: Also worth noting when we talk about naming:
in C# "A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field."
In Java or JS this term has a different meaning.

Answer (score 31):

You could have a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) as it tries to take the pain out of writing boiler plate Java code. It allows you to either use `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations, which will provide `getBlah()` and `setBlah()` methods:

```
public class GetterSetterExample {
  @Getter @Setter private int age = 10;
}
```

Or you can just use `@Data` and it will automatically implement your `hashCode()`, `equals()`, `toString()` and getter methods, along with setters on non-final fields:

```
@Data public class DataExample {
  private String name;
}
```

Problems I have found with the project, however, are that it's all a bit voodoo, which can be off-putting, and that you have to install an Eclipse (or what ever) plugin to get auto compilation to work.

Comment: And a further problem is that if you use Lombok, then you're no longer writing portable Java code.

Comment: can you explain **portable** here?

Comment: @NealGafter what do you mean that the Java code is no longer portable?

Comment: I think @NealGafter is referring to the fact that Lombok must be supported by your editor and build tools, so your code might not work on all development platforms/environments.

Comment: As a point of reference for anyone looking for C# behavior this isn't quite it you would still call to


`GetterSetterExample.getAge`


C# setters that allow setting the properties with = would fail here
 `GetterSetterExample.setAge = 10
`


would not work using the Lombok syntax

Answer (score 18):

Properties are not only convenient in terms of writing `getters` and `setters` encapsulated in a unit , but also they provide a good syntax at the point of call.

```
Window.Title =  "New"; //which looks natural
```

while with `getters` and `setters` it is usually

```
Window.setTitle("New");
```

Comment: It's even worse to do something like an increment:

C#: Thing.Number += 1

Java: Thing.setNumber(Thing.getNumber() + 1)

Comment: This does not answer the question, but instead just describes differences in syntax.

Comment: Well if you just used public fields in java then you would be able to do Window.Title = "New" just like in C# - without the need for properties. I never quite understood the point of them in C# but I use them anyway because they are convenient.

Comment: @ozzy432836 well here is the case.. u can assign Window.Title = "New" and for you it is a variable. But in C# u can add a constraint to it telling if Window.Title = "@some invalid value" then reject it. Its that beauty of C# I like. Wish java world understood it! its like we can write code in assembly language, then why higher level languages evolved! For me I feel java world got an ego on this!

Answer (score 6):

There has been a proposal to add C#-like support for properties (and events) to Java, but it looks like this is rejected for the next version of Java (Java 7).

See:

- [Why will there be no native properties in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710266/why-will-there-be-no-native-properties-in-java-7)
- [Java Properties Without Getters and Setters](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-properties-without)

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a private variable, and write the methods by hand. However, if you are using Eclipse, you can click on a variable, select "Source" and "Generate getters and setters." This is about as convenient as C# properties.

Comment: NetBeans also offers such automated method generation

Comment: I wouldnt say it is as convenient as c#, because I tend to rename properties and instead of updating the name of a property, I have to updating two methods and one variable;

Comment: It's not "as convenient". C# properties offer many more conveniences over standard getters/setters.