# I'd like to set and get instance properties with methods in a class

Tags: java, class

I am a beginner of Java. I have a question.

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private int num;

    Foo(String name, int num) {
        this.name = name;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return this.num;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Tom";
        int num = 60;
        Foo bar = new Foo(name, num);
    }
}
```

Instead of this typical style of class on Java, I'd like to set and get instance properties with `getter()` and `setter()` method like...

```
public void setter(String p) {
    this.p = p;
}

public String getter(String q) {
    return this.q
}
```

I know these don't work, but I want to write Java method like following these codes in `Python`.

```
setattr(self, key, val)
getattr(self, key)
```

Would you please give me some pieces of advices?

Comment: Do you want to input any value to the `setter` method?

Comment: could you explain the reason behind this, or why you would like to not use the java standard?

Comment: You could use Reflection API to write universal getter and setter methods that find fields by name. But its a bad idea in your case and you will have problems with types. So I would suggest to stick with java code standard if you want to code java.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your comment. I want to use `setter` in the constructor because I don't want to write every properties even when I make an instance like `Foo bar = new Foo(name, num);`..haha I could implement codes in `Python`, `PHP`, `Go`, so I usually use `setter()` in constructor.

Comment: @ArcticLord Thank you for your comment. I checked about `reflection`. in some web pages, they don't recommend to use `reflection`. Maybe I must follow Java standard way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Java does not support properties.

The only way to do this is through **accessor** and **mutator** (get/set) methods like you did at the top.

See: [does java have something similar to C# properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963243/does-java-have-something-similar-to-c-sharp-properties)

Comment: The answer is a bit rough and will require to go check associated question, meanwhile it is mainly correct : java do not provides access through static methods to instances variables.

Comment: Thank you Brandon. That is why I couldn't find information in Japanese when I searched about that. And thank you for your link.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Riduidel. I understand.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve can be done using **reflection** as next:

```
// get the field "key" from the class "Foo"
Field field = Foo.class.getField("key");
// make it accessible as it is a private field
field.setAccessible(true);
// set the value of this field to val on the instance self
field.set(self, val);
```

More details about reflection [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. I didn't know about `reflection`. I check and learn about that. Thanks.