# GraphStream setAttribute( ) vs addAttribute( )

Tags: java, graphstream

I don't understand the difference between ***setAttribute( )*** and ***addAttribute( )*** in `GraphStream1.3`.

In `GraphStream`'s `Element` [API 1.3](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/1.3/org/graphstream/graph/Element.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) it's explained that setAttribute is

> Like addAttribute() but for consistency.

what does it means?

Comment: Which version are you referring? I don't see `addAttribute` in Element for version 2.0

Comment: I'm using version 1.3, thanks for the input, the hyper link was deleted by mistake.

Comment: probably `consistency` means avoiding duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that they mean `api consistency` with this wording; overall consistency between their own API or what developers might expect to find in general in the API of a Java library.

For example `properties` on Java Beans (pojo's) are usually implemented as `getter` and `setter` methods by convention (rather than language features, as can be found in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963243/does-java-have-something-similar-to-c-sharp-properties)).

So perhaps the `graphstream` devs wanted to have both `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` in a similar fashion.

This can be confirmed by checking one of the `Known Implementing Classes` as listed in the javadoc; for example [org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractElement](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/1.3/org/graphstream/graph/implementations/AbstractElement.html), where the `setAttribute` method is just calling `addAttribute` directly:

```java
    /**
     * @complexity O(log(n)) with n being the number of attributes of this
     *             element.
     */
    public void setAttribute(String attribute, Object... values) {
        addAttribute(attribute, values);
    }
```

Taken from the [decompiled](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui) jar or the [sources jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/graphstream/gs-core/1.3/) of the [following](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graphstream/gs-core/1.3) artifact.